# Cannot make clickable elements, RoR

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have root page with some pics and text, so that visitors could click either on pics or text and be forwarded to desired part of my app.

**My basic html code**

```
   <div class="tprod">
      <div class="titimg"><%= image_tag('atkr_1.jpg') %></div>
      <div class="text">
         <div class="antr">
            <h2><%= I18n.t 'Waste_recycling_equipment'%></h2>
         </div>
    <%= I18n.t 'waste_intro_start' %> 
      </div>
      <%= link_to (I18n.t 'read_more'),products_path(:category => @waste_root.name) %>
   </div>
```

When I try to add link_to for image_tag, suddenly image changes position.

```
<div class="tprod">
      <div class="titimg"> <%= link_to image_tag('energ_1.jpg') %>  </div>
      <div class="text">
         <div class="antr">
            <h2><%= I18n.t 'Energy_wood_machinery'%></h2>
         </div>
        <%= I18n.t 'energo_intro_start' %> 
      </div>
     <%= link_to (I18n.t 'read_more'),products_path(:category => @energy_root.name) %>
   </div>
```

Looks like [this](http://gyazo.com/4d137fa917060e2e48284567007e191f)

I was wondering it is because now it is link element combined with image_tag so It has different CSS formatting?

Application is available [here](http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your `#content .mainprods .tprod a` css affecting the anchor tag you're creating around the image.

You need to make the css more specific in order to only specify the anchor at the bottom. For example, if you added `:class => "read-more"` to the bottom `link_to`, then you could change the css selector to `#content .mainprods .tprod a.read-more` and only style the bottom link. There's a number of different approaches for that.

Also, as an aside, `(I18n.t 'read_more')` is bad practice.. It should be `I18n.t('read_more')` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me on Chrome:

[image]

---

**Formatting**

The likely issue you have is with your `CSS`, not `Rails`

After looking at your picture, I would say the issue is likely to be with your use of `float: left;`

[`float`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float) basically treats the element as an inline item, meaning if its width / structure is not consistent in even the smallest degree, it can cause issues like you're seeing.

To fix this, I would strongly recommend using the good old `<table>` tag. It might seem old skool, but it's certainly what you've got here:

```
<table class="items">
   <tr>
       <% @items.each do |item| %>
           <td><%= image_tag item.image.url %></td>
       <% end %>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <% @items.each do |item| %>
           <td><%= item.description %></td>
       <% end %>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This might get frowned upon for the use of `<table>`, but I believe it will work for what you've got here.